# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to Node so bear with me.

I have a Node server which requires `ws` so I install it with:

```
$ npm install ws
/private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC
└─┬ ws@1.1.1 
  ├── options@0.0.6 
  └── ultron@1.0.2 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC/package.json'
npm WARN SVC No description
npm WARN SVC No repository field.
npm WARN SVC No README data
npm WARN SVC No license field.
```

I then run the server using:

```
$ npm run server.js 
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "server.js"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! path /private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/www/html/WebRTC/SVC/npm-debug.log
```

but am getting errors mentioning no `package.json`.

Looking through `npm-debug.log` it seems pretty much the same.

Can someone shed some light on what `enoent` is and what sort of `package.json` file I need.

I was expecting this script to run out of the box so a little puzzled.

Comment: Did you run `npm init` when you started the project?

Comment: Try `node server.js` instead of `npm run server.js`.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I know it's old, but "npm init" did the trick for me. I'm using Visual Studio Code Insiders and created dotnet core mvc project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type

```
npm run server.js
```

npm tries to find entry named `server.js` in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file (see [npm docs on scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)  for details).

`package.json`, simplified, describes your app's dependencies and environment.

As you don't have such file, npm fails with `ENOENT`, which is an abbreviation for `Error NO ENTry`.
Basically, in your case, you just want to `node server.js` to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me:

```
npm install -g expo-cli --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Following commands worked for me:

```
npm cache clean --force
node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

1. Reinstall npm: open cmd as an administrator and run `npm uninstall -g npm`
2. Go to your directory and open cmd
3. Clear npm Cache using `npm cache clean -f`
4. Now you can update npm using `npm install -g npm@latest`